# Making the image darker, but not the icons

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="img-box">
               <i class="ion-play"></i>
               <img src="resources/images/john.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Basically, when i hover the img-box, i want the image to get darker, but not the icon.
My css now:

```
.img-box:hover {
color: #fff;
transition: filter 0.3s, color 0.3s;
filter: brightness(30%);}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the selector `.img-box:hover > img` so the style is applied to the `<img>` and not the whole `<div>`.

```css
.img-box:hover > img {
  color: #fff;
  transition: filter 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  filter: brightness(30%);
}

.ion-play {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <i class="ion-play">icon</i>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
</div>
```

Note: You may also use the selector `.img-box:hover img`. It depends how your markup is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to absolutely position your icons relative to the `img-box` for the desired behaviour.

Something like this:

```css
.img-box:hover {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  transition: filter 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  filter: brightness(30%);
}

.ion-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <i class="ion-play"></i>
  <img src="resources/images/john.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.img-box:hover img {
  color: #fff;
  transition: filter 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  filter: brightness(30%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS , it will solve your problem.

```css
.img-box:hover img {
  color: #fff;
  transition: filter 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  filter: brightness(30%);
}
```